# React is getting the wrong path

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a react app and I am trying to get ongs/:id from node.js server, but it is accessing only get ongs.

```
try {
            const response = await api.get(`ongs/${id}`);

            localStorage.setItem('ongId', id);
            localStorage.setItem('ongName', response.data.name);

            history.push('/profile');
        } catch(error) {
            alert('Falha no login, tente novamente.');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, the variable id was null, so it wasn't passing to ${id}.